# NFL games where defense scored more points that the offense

Tags: american-football, nfl

How many games since the merger has the winning team scored more defensive touchdowns than offensive touchdowns? Extra points don't count for the defense or the offense.
Also list the game where the defense has scored the most points.

Comment: When you say defense scores more than offense, do you mean for one of the teams, or for both of the teams?  Does it need to be the winning team?  (I suspect there are a very large number of losing teams where this happened, say, a single INT/TD and no offensive points).  Also, what are you crediting to the offense - only TDs (6 points), or does special teams (FG, XP) count for the offense?

Comment: I meant the winning team. The offense gets the touchdown if they make the touchdown. And the defense gets touchdown if they make the touchdown. FG,Xp don't count for the defense or offense. I will edit my question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure this happens on a somewhat frequent basis (particularly in the lower scoring era pre-1990s), but it's somewhat challenging to get to the exact answer as "defensive touchdown" isn't usually in the box score.  I'll edit this when I have time to pull it.

Here's one, though, that every NFL fan from 2006 should remember... [Chicago 24, Arizona 23](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/200610160crd.htm).  Zero offensive points, 2 defensive touchdowns and a special teams touchdown (plus a field goal).

Comment: For the sake of argument, using your example, I would assume to include field goals as offensive, even though it is a special teams unit.  Offensive touchdowns and field goals are the standard modes of scoring.  Anything else would be considered defensive I think.  (ah, but I see the OPs preference)

Comment: @JasonPSallinger That was asked in the OP, and specifically requested to be disregarded, yes.  (And yes, typically in these they would compare (Defensive scores and maybe PR/KR TDs) to (everything else), but...)

Comment: @JasonPSallinger I have edited the question now to add more clarity